# How to add devexpress xtragird's repository lookup edit item into dictionary

Tags: vb.net

Dim dictRepositoryItem as new Dictionary(of Datatable, of gridcontrol.repository itemlookupedit)

dictRepositoryItem.add(Datatable1,repositoryitemlookupedit1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct type in the dictionary.

```
Dim dictRepositoryItem As New Dictionary(Of DataTable, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit)
dictRepositoryItem.Add(Datatable1, repositoryitemlookupedit1)
```

Comment: It's working.Thank you